# SQLs directly to the Broker

Tags: content-delivery, broker

I need to do a SQL directly to the broker to get some data from a component and I don't really know how. I mean, I don't know the table structure to be able to from a tcm get all the component data for example.

I don't have any clue how the db is organized but I really need to do the query directly to the broker. Please, don't point me to the core service, just a little bit of help on how to get all the data from a component.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Direct query is asking for troubles :) Maybe if you can explain more in detail what are your requirements we can propose alternative approaches. Not necessarily Core Service. Tridion is very rich in supported API's and options to risk going trough the unsupported route.

Comment: Keep in mind that data in the broker is the result of a template executed at publish time. If this template outputs garbage, you get garbage - not all implementations publish structured data, many will output "pre-rendered" html...

Comment: By now it's clear: people advise against querying the broker DB through SQL, but instead suggest using the Content Delivery Query API. If you're having trouble writing a specific query, just post a question describing the query that you are trying to write and the code that shows how far you've gotten. Challenges to complete a code sample lure in the Tridi-geeks. :-)

Comment: -1. Your question doesn't actually say what you are trying to achieve. Querying data from the broker using SQL is not a valid end in itself. Please share your actual problem.

Comment: Okay, let's explain it a little bit more!

What I really want is to create a RSS of components of schema X that will be updated automatically each time a component is published (within a page). I'm using some code from dynamic content but I don't get new elements on the list (or its changes) without publishing the dynamic template again and is something I want to do as the RSS should be something automatic

Comment: The API will easily give you a list of published components that are based on a given schema. I don't see any need to write SQL. And of course, if they aren't published yet, then querying the broker database directly still won't help you.

Comment: Okay, now I'm reaching it and I can get a list of components but I come with a small problem when I want to sort them based on the modification date. I mean I have a criteria but I don't know how to refer to that field (is not a field of the schema is the component modification date).

Comment: I'm happy, achieved a lot for today :) but can't make any structuregroup related criteria to work.

Comment: Get SQL Developer from Oracle (it's free) or a trial version of Toad and reverse engineer the DB schema via these tools if you want more info about it. Nothing wrong with querying the DB. It is a sure way to debug.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I wouldn't query it directly at all: You already said you don't have a clue about the structure, so image you would finally be able to write your queries, you'd probably have to change it when a new version comes out.

I'd try out the following options:

- Use BrokerQueries. Robert Curlette has some articles on his blog (e.g. http://www.curlette.com/?p=383), but you can also find examples on SDL Live Content
- My preferred way: Publish the content + metadata to the broker as readeble XML (you define the structure based on the schemas), use the Tridion Broker API to query for the content/metadata and build up your own custom objects in your application.

Whatever you do, try to avoid a direct query at all times..

Comment: Thank you, I will try to figure it out fromt he links you sent me. Where to get the broker API? sdltridionworld downloads are broken :(

Comment: you can find the dll's in the /BIN folder of your Tridion 2011 installation. Look for Tridion.ContentDelivery.dll and Tridion.ContentDelivery.Configuration.dll

Comment: SDL Tridion World requires a login.  If you do not have an account and are actively working on a client project, you could request a login account from SDL Customer Support.  Note that Customer Support may ask for validation of work from the client.

Comment: Thank you all! I use the visitor account but honestly, I was hoping for something more close to the MSDN but yeah, a man can dream.

Comment: If you go to SDL Tridion World, then choose the login option on the right, and provide the details you have gotten from Customer Support. You will see a DOWNLOADS option in the navigation. This contains a Documentation -> SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 link and on that page you can find the CHM files. The SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 Content delivery ASP.NET API will contain information about the `Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent` namespace which contains the Broker Query stuff.

Comment: [SDL Live Content](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com) has the full overview of all the ways to interact with SDL Tridion and the various APIs (including a click-able "architecture" diagram). This provides background and even some code examples, giving comparable context to MSDN articles (and the ability to leave comments). This is distinct from the downloadable CHM files for just the API.

Answer (score 9):

+1 for a question that comes up frequently, though everyone say not to query SDL Tridion databases. It's easy to query "content" from the storage broker (hints below).

Some clarifications:

### Content Manager vs. Content Delivery

The **Content Management System** (CMS) and its database stores component and pages as well as their history. In CMS, can "inspect component data" using the Core Service as well as the TOM.NET API (in templates).

However, **Content Delivery** (CD) stores pages and *component presentations*, the rendered output of a component and a component template. You retrieve these as files or through the CD API. *The Broker lives in CD.*

CMS-side component information is available in CD if it's metadata or if your templates outputted them.

### Storage

The broker database is just one of several ways to store rendered output. It assumes you're using dynamic component templates and storage configuration that places component presentations in the database, which may not apply for a given publication, implementation, or CMS.

As a practical example of why querying either the CM or CD databases is a bad idea, sometime between SDL Tridion R5.3 and 2011, the broker database changed from comma-separated values in the `CUSTOM_META` table to repeated key-value pairs. Also in SDL Tridion 2011 (SP1, I think), file-based metadata was deprecated.

### Inspecting Component Data

Use a component's Source tab to see how SDL Tridion stores it on the CM-Side. Otherwise see my posts on how to get it with a trivial [XSLT template](http://www.createandbreak.net/2012/01/inspect-component-details-with-xslt.html) or [simple C# code](http://www.createandbreak.net/2012/04/inspect-component-xml-with-c.html).

To get fields from the delivery-side, consider starting with [SDL Live Content's CD section](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_C72D061178C64B88A93134DE051A082C) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)).

I sometimes *check* (read-only, i.e. `select` statements) the broker database to troubleshoot. For example, you might need to check the `COMPONENT_PRESENTATIONS` and `CUSTOM_META` tables to confirm configuration settings or troubleshoot something like encoding.

**However, again there are much easier and supported ways to get at components and component presentations.**

Comment: All good input. Just consider the DB to be read only when you use SQL.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I edited the answer to emphasize read-only access.

Answer (score 4):

Just don't do it. Use the API.

Answer (score 3):

as everybody said don't do it, i will give your example why...

We have upgraded one of our client to New Tridion Version, their 80% of the CD logic was implemented using SQL queries.

When we upgraded, whole system stopped working, as Broker DB schema was changed.(though we knew this in advance :))

It was a major issue understanding those and then converting queries to updated schema. But we took the harder side, understood the whole logic and converted almost all SQL Queries to broker queries, so that **future upgrades** wouldn't face same problem.

Secondly CoreService is for accessing CMS not broker.